# URL rewriting that visibly rewrites (changes the URL in the address bar)

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I asked sort of the complement of this question before:

[Mod_rewrite invisibly: works when target is a file, not when it's a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685030/modrewrite-invisibly)

Now I actually want a rewrite to happen visibly, because I've switched URL schemes and although I want the old links to work, I want the user to see the new URL scheme.

So this works

```
RewriteRule ^oldscheme/(.*)/?$  newscheme/$1
```

But the URL in the address bar remains as `http://example.com/oldscheme/foo`.

What's the right way to do a visible rewrite, preferably just with mod_rewrite as opposed to something kludgy with Location redirects or somesuch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I cannot leave comments now, I'll post my addition to Ignacio's comment here.

You actually should post a 301 (Moved Permanently) redirect, as you're describing there's a new site directory structure. So your RewriteRule should read

```
RewriteRule ^oldscheme/(.*)/?$  newscheme/$1  [R=301]
```

Answer (score 4):

It turns out adding a "redirect" code does the trick:

```
RewriteRule ^oldscheme/(.*)/?$  newscheme/$1  [R]
```

Obvious in retrospect, but hopefully this makes the answer more searchable.
I found it on this excellent "cheat sheet":

http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet/

Comment: The [R] parameter 'forces' a rewrite of the URL if i'm correct.

Comment: It results in a response code of 302 along with a `Location` header being sent to the browser. Without it, only internal httpd structures are modified if possible.