# Rewrite pretty url for a link

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need help, i have a link like **http://website.com/index.php?catg=code&subcatg=code_name** ,
 when i click on this link, it display this url in address bar and same in task bar on mouse over.

I tried this,

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index/([A-Za-z0-9-\+]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-\+]+)/?$ http://website.com/index.php?catg=$1&subcatg=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

but it didn't worked.
 Is it possible to rewrite this url to **http://website.com/index/code/code-name** ???
and it must look pretty url in both address & task bar.

please help
Thanks

Comment: Then what should i do to solve this & on which kind source Rewrite rule can be applied?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this might be what you are looking for:

[URL rewriting that visibly rewrites (changes the URL in the address bar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088411/url-rewriting-that-visibly-rewrites-changes-the-url-in-the-address-bar)

You might just need to add the "R" flag.

Comment: Thanks, but i didn't got that i want