# URL Rewriting invisibly - How to prevent rewritten URL to appear in the address bar?

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have browsed the other topics, including this one: [Mod_rewrite invisibly: works when target is a file, not when it's a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685030/mod-rewrite-invisibly-works-when-target-is-a-file-not-when-its-a-directory), but I can't find a solution to my problem.

I have the following rewriting rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ ./index.php?s=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ ./index.php?s=$1 [L,NC]
```

What it does is to write anything like `http://myaddress/parameter` to `http://myaddress/index.php?s=parameter` and show this new rewritten address in the browser's address bar.

How can I make rewriting without showing the rewritten URL in the address bar?

---

**Edit**

This is the content of my .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_\-]+)/?$ index.php?s=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\/?$ index.php?u=$1&s=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\/?$ index.php?u1=$1&u2=$2&s=$3 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No need for 2 rules that do the same job (the only difference is presence of trailing slash).

2. No need to have `a-zA-Z` in pattern if you have `[NC]` flag -- `a-z` is enough.

3. Try rule without `./`

Considering all the above mentioned the rule will become:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_\-]+)/?$ index.php?s=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

**P.S.**
I have also added the `QSA` flag to preserve original query string (if present).

The rule is tested and is working fine. If it still does not work for you then post **ALL** rewrite rules that you have.

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work, I have edited my question to post the rewrite rules that I have.

Comment: @AntonioJunior Sorry, but there is NO way that THESE rules will do a redirect (URL changes in browser). If you can edit server config then enable rewrite debugging (`RewriteLogLevel 9`), restart Apache, try this problematic URL and check the rewrite log -- it should tell you what is going on. Maybe it is your PHP code that does redirect -- to check create empty PHP file and use it instead of index.php in rewrite rules. I would also suggest to **clear browser cache** or try another browser ... as modern browsers do cache redirects.

Comment: Hi, LazyOne, thank you so much! In fact, I was doing a redirect in the PHP code and I didn't remember that until you pointed it out. Thanks for the patience in explaining.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ index.php?s=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. It keeps showing the rewritten URL in the address bar. I have edited my post to show the rewriting rules.